# Need to resolve datatable var reference in JSF 1.1

Tags: jsf

I am creating a dynamic datatable in JSF 1.1.

```
HTMLDataTable table = new HTMLDataTabl();
table.setVar("rowObj");
table.setValue(.....);
```

I'm trying to evaluate the value of `var`, but it returns `null`.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ctx.getApplication.getVariableResolver().resolveVariable("#{rowObj}"); // null.
```

How to get value of variable reference of datatable using JSF 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the evaluated value of the `var` attribute. It's not available in the component tree. It's only available in the rendered output, while the datatable is iterating over its `value`.

If you elaborate what exactly you need it for, then we may be able to suggest the right approaches. Probably you just need the `value` instead of `var` or maybe you don't need it at all.

Comment: i have assigned expression value to column in datatable, and in that i need to check whether that value is greater than say 25, if yes then i have to truncate the same value and need to re-assign to that column again.